# AWS PHP web service and Android app load handling

Tags: php, android, rest, web-services, amazon-web-services

I am developing an Android App with its Rest API web-services coded using PHP running on AWS EC-2. The database on AWS is MySQL. I have 1,00,000 users signed up for beta testing.

The push notification services are triggered using One Signal.

Now the issue that I am facing is that whenever I send out a push notification, the app hits an API web-service call to download certain text data from the server when the notification is tapped (Most users do this immediately or within minutes of receiving the notification). This puts load on the server and the server takes long to respond, as the service requests are sequentially serviced. But when only a few hundred users try simultaneously to hit the same API web service call, it works fine. Typically I get the response within 1 sec on postman during non-peak time and during peak time it takes anywhere between 1 minute to 2 minutes depending on how long the sequence is.

This is the first time I am attempting to build a system of this magnitude, I have tried reading and implementing all the tutorials etc over the past few weeks but have not found a solution.

Any pointers would be helpful and highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "download certain text data from the server" - Could you please provide more info on this? Do you download and process the data and send it back to the app? Where is the data stored?

Comment: Sure, so the data is retrieved by the web service from the MySQL database and sent to the app in the web service response. The data is not processed, just queried to the MySQL on AWS and sent to the app. The data size is approx 15-20KB

Comment: "puts load on the server" - RDS Database or the EC2 instance?

Comment: I am using an EC-2 instance. Is MySQL wrong choice of database? Should go for RDS?

Comment: Yes, RDS is easier to maintain and have you scaling option like Read Replicas, automated backups, etc. some people have it on ec2 but its difficult to maintain for a dev.

Comment: If you use RDS, with Read Replicas, you can have a ready only database for your push notification services to use. (I guess you are not making writes), it can take some load off the actual database.

Comment: I am making a few small updates in the database like updating the timestamp of when this data is downloaded. 

Thanks for this pointer. I will look on these lines.

Comment: I have implemented RDS MySQL, still no change in the situation. I was monitoring the RDS DB instance, usage was 2.3% for the CPU and max  53 concurrent requests were received. I am unable to pinpoint the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured a load balancer in the ec2 with the AMI. I did take suggestions here and update the database to RDS.  That seems to have solved the problem now. I will update the post as and when I learn more about AWS